# How to map (Either String (a -> b)) to (Either String [(a -> b)])

Tags: haskell, monads, either

I try to find a solution on an exercise of my own, with the following requirements :

- We need to move an object against a given sequence.
- A sequence is composed of actions.

Here are the possible actions : F, L, R

- F : move Forward
- L : rotate 90° to the left
- R : rotate 90° to the right

A sequence is then represented by a string, like this :

`"FFLRLFF"`

I want to parse the above sequence (and handle errors) and then bind each action to a function, like this :

```
parseAction :: Char -> Either String (a -> a)
parseAction 'F' = Right moveForward
parseAction 'L' = Right turnLeft
parseAction 'R' = Right turnRight
parseAction s   = Left ("Unkown action : " ++ [s])

-- Implementation omitted
moveForward :: a -> a
turnLeft :: a -> a
turnRight :: a -> a
```

Now what I want is something with the following signature :

```
parseSequence :: String -> Either String [(a -> a)]
```

I want to parse a full sequence by using many times `parseAction` function, and fails when that one returns Left. I'm stuck on how can I implement this function.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: I was going to suggest Hoogle, but I found it surprisingly hard to get Hoogle to give me the right answer. I started with `(Char -> Either String (a -> a)) -> (String -> Either String [(a -> a)])`, but that gave results; getting the right answer required both the insight that I could replace `a -> a` with the more-polymorphic `a`, and that I could replace `Either String` with the more-polymorphic `f`. Only then did it suggest `mapM`. Oh well, at least I didn't have to have the insight that `Char` and `String` could be replaced with the more-polymorphic `b` and `[b]`.

Comment: Isn't `id` the only valid functions of type `a -> a`? (Ignoring errors, undefined, unsafe side effects, etc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

where

```
a ~ Char
b ~ (a -> a)
m ~ (Either String)
```

So an implementation is simply:

```
parseSequence :: String -> Either String [a -> a]
parseSequence = mapM parseAction
```

As an aside, note that your `parseAction` doesn't really want to be using type `(a -> a)`, which must work for *any* type `a`, chosen by the person calling the function. You instead want it to use type `(Location -> Location)`, where Location is whatever type you're using to represent the location of the object you're moving.

Equivalently to mapM, you can (as suggested by duplode) instead use traverse, which is slightly more general. In recent versions of GHC traverse is in Prelude; in older versions you may have to import it from Data.Traversable to use it.

Comment: Indeed, the parseAction is actually working on lawn mower :), but for the purpose of explanation, I didn't explain it.

Answer (score 7):

*Note: For extra clarity, I am going to use `Thing -> Thing` rather than `a -> a`.*

You need `traverse`:

```
traverse parseAction
  :: Traversable t => t Char -> Either String (t (Thing -> Thing))
```

In your case, `t` is `[]`, and so, `t Char` is `String`. `traverse parseAction` will walk across the `String`, generating one action for each `Char` and collecting the results. `traverse` uses the `Applicative` instance of `Either` to handle `Left`s and `Right`s, stopping at the first `Left`.

P.S.: `mapM` in amalloy's answer is, in this case, equivalent to `traverse`. The only difference between them is that `traverse` is more general, as it only requires `Applicative` (rather than `Monad`) from the functor you use while traversing.

Comment: So does mapM handle Left aswell ?

Comment: @MaximeB. Yes, it does. In practice, there is no difference between `mapM` and `traverse` other than the type signature. (It might be said that `mapM` only exists because, back when it was introduced, `Applicative` and `Traversable` didn't exist yet. It worked just the same because you can make every `Monad` an `Applicative`. Nowadays that is reflected in `Applicative` being a superclass of `Monad`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you map parseAction over your source string you get part of the way. In GHCi:

```
> :type map parseAction "FFRRF"
[Either String (a->a)]
```

So now you can fold this into a single Either value

```
validActions = foldr f (Right [])
   where
      f (Left str) _ = Left str
      f (Right x) (Right xs) = Right (x:xs)
      f (Right x) (Left str) = error "Can't happen"
```

However this has an annoying "error" case. So to get rid of that:

```
import Data.Either

validActions vs = if null ls then Right rs else Left $ head ls
   where (ls, rs) = partitionEithers vs
```

Comment: But amalloy's solution is neater.

Comment: Hiding your "impossible" error behind `head` and `tail` is much worse.